# Function won't execute after animation

Tags: jquery, function, animation, anonymous-function

After the animation below is finished, I want to run a function to do some stuff, but the function won't execute (no exceptions thrown).

What am I doing wrong?

```
rb.animate({
    'right': '0'
}, { duration: this.animSpeed, queue: false }, function() {
    block.find('.menu-handle').css({
        'visibility': 'visible'
    });
    block.find('.sub-menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you place it in an example JSFiddle? One thing you need to be aware of is that if the final value is the current/starting value, no animation occurs and the end event will not fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `complete` in the options, since you're using [the two-argument version of `animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options).

```
rb.animate({
    'right': '100'
}, { duration: 1000, queue: false , complete: function() {
    block.find('.menu-handle').css({
        visibility': 'visible'
    });
    block.find('.sub-menu').hide();
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
rb.animate({
    'right': '0'
}, { duration: this.animSpeed, queue: false ,complete: function() {// use complete
    block.find('.menu-handle').css({
        'visibility': 'visible'
    });
    block.find('.sub-menu').hide();
}});//// use complete in the second option of animate function
```

Docs http://api.jquery.com/animate/